# Unity closes debugger on run

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, tabs, console

I am very new to unity so you shouldn't think the answer is to obvious for me to have not tried it. My code prints a simple string to the console after a certain amount of time passes but the problem is not with my code, when I press play on unity 5 Mac OS basically every other tab(such as project, hierarchy, inspector, debugger etc) close so I just see a grey window with my scene, able to be played, but I can't get any information from my console since it is now just a grey window. I've tried opening the console separately with the window tab but that also turns completely grey until I stop playing my scene. So how do I run the game while also having my tabs open, if possible or atleast the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having "Maximize on play" on in gameMode. turn this off.
[image]